# DirectShow custom filter inside project C++

Tags: c++, windows-7, directshow

I'm currently writing a custom transform filter like shown in MSDN tutorial : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
.

It's written with my main DirectShow projet (I'm not making a DLL with the filter)

The problem is I dont know how to create/use the filter. I have tried the CoCreateInstance

```
SmartPtr<IFilterRotation> _pRotation = 0; // My custom filter
if(!SUCCEEDED(_mResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterRotation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&_pRotation)))
{
      return _mResult;
}
```

But It returns the following error : REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Here is all the elements I have override for the moment:

```
#pragma once

// {4A80F8B5-CFB0-4dc6-96C5-DA427B6DB8BD}
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_FiltreRotation, 
0x4a80f8b5, 0xcfb0, 0x4dc6, 0x96, 0xc5, 0xda, 0x42, 0x7b, 0x6d, 0xb8, 0xbd);


    class IFilterRotation: public CTransformFilter
    {
    public:
        IFilterRotation(void);
        ~IFilterRotation(void);

    HRESULT IFilterRotation::CheckInputType(const CMediaType *vpMediaTypeIn);
    HRESULT IFilterRotation::CheckTransform(const CMediaType *vpMediaTypeIn,
                                            const CMediaType *vpMediaTypeOut);
    HRESULT IFilterRotation::DecideBufferSize(IMemAllocator *vpAllocation,
                                              ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES *vppRequeteProprieteIn);
    HRESULT IFilterRotation::GetMediaType(int vPosition,
                                          CMediaType *vpMediaType);
    HRESULT IFilterRotation::Transform(IMediaSample *vpMediaSampleIn,
                                       IMediaSample *vpMediaSampleOut);

    };
```

Am i missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic chain is here as follows:

- `CoCreateInstance` takes `CLSID_Xxx`
- `CLSID_Xxx` needs to not only be defined, but should be also properly served by your project

  - ... which means that you should have a `CFactoryTemplate` instance mapping CLSID to your class

You can refer to one of the Windows SDK samples for details, I recommend [`EZRGB24`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in particular.

You only show you have CLSID defined within the project. Class `IFilterRotation` does not look good to me (you typically don't inherit I-thing from C-thing, but it's a naming matter though). You don't show if you have a `CFactoryTemplate`, which I suppose you don't have.

However this all is true when you put your filter into DLL. In your case you don't seem to register COM class at all, so `CoCreateInstance` does not work for you. Your options are either put the class into DLL, or `CoRegisterClassObject` this class to enable its visibility for `CoCreateInstance`, or create a simple C++ instance of the class (operator new or stack/static instance) which you then pass directly to `AddFilter`.

Comment: I thought CFactoryTemplate must be used only in DLL so that is why i haven't implemented it. I will go take a look to the sample. I think it's exactly what I needed to understand clearly how custom transformation filter works. And Yeah my class name is wrong for what i'm currently doing :/.

Comment: When you `AddFilter` your filter, it has ot be a COM interface pointer, but it does not have to have full COM registration, and full DirectShow registration. On the opposite, `CoCreateInstance` supposes you do have COM registration for this COM class.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly, When I run the program I have a bug. A messagebox appear at the construction : [title] ASSERT failed [message] !!szObjectName ^ !!wszObjectName at Line 892 of (sdkpath)\baseclasses\wxdebug.cpp Continue? (cancel to debug) [button] yes , no , cancel. Do you have any idea what is it? In wxdebug.cpp it's linked to the function DbgRegisterObjectCreation so it looks like to be a registeration (prob COM?) problem.

Comment: I guess you're passing NULL somewhere where it reaches `CBaseObject` consturctor, and you are supposed to pass non-`NULL` object name there. This is a debugging thing.

Answer (score 1):

IFilterRotation should have private constructor and destructor, because it is a COM object (you want to prevent creating an instance on stack, or by calling new, because of reference counting.. you want to prevent destroying such object by calling delete as well). It will destroy itself once the reference count drops to zero.
Add static method for creating an instance of IFilterRotation.

```
static IFilterRotation * createInstance()
{
    IFilterRotation  * const pFilterRotation( new (std::nothrow) IFilterRotation() );

    if( pFilterRotation )
        pFilterRotation->AddRef();

    return pFilterRotation;
}
```

You can use `CoCreateInstance()` only if you have your filter as a separate DLL. Of course, you also have to register such DLL before using `CoCreateInstance()`.